# Probability random variable binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Every day, a lecture may be canceled due to inclement weather with probability 0.05. Class
cancelations on different days are independent.
(a) There are 15 classes left this semester. Compute the probability that at least 4 of
them get canceled.
(b) Compute the probability that the tenth class this semester is the third class that gets
canceled.

How to solve the part b of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For the tenth class this semester to be the third class that gets cancelled, you want

- exactly two of the first nine classes to be cancelled
- the tenth class to be cancelled

Comment: Well i tried to construct it like:  (9c2 * 1c1)/10c3. Where does that goes wrong?

Comment: $0.05$ and $0.95$ should appear in the calculation - this involves binomial distributions - while 10c3 should not

Comment: (9c1* (.05)^2*(1-.05)^7)+(1c1*(.05)) is it right..?if not please point out the problem

Comment: 9c2  as you had earlier, but otherwise yes

Comment: But still this is not yielding the correct answer (9c2* (.05)^2 * (1-.05)^7)+(1c1*(.05)) .The correct answer is: 0.00314

Comment: Multiplication rather than addition, so ${9 \choose 2}\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^7\times {1 \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^1$